# Tag green background in revision is too light

Tags: feature-request, design, revisions-list

The green background color for the revision list is too light. [Sample revision list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/345234/revisions). Can this be improved?

New UI:

> [image: new UI]

Please refer the old UI:

> [image: old UI]